# How to make list of all classes in the page using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, class

I was given an eshop after someone else who wasnt really caring about the site performance and made a really anti-performance CSS, and since no CSS minifyer works crossbrowser-properly on such a huge CSS file (not even eshop's own) I decided to clear CSS by myself, to do that I would need complete list of classes used on page - how to get complete list of classes used on the page in jQuery?

(Somtehing I could e.g. loop-write into console,... And I am looking rather for a how to do in jQuery than a complete solution (In such things I never belive third-side x) )

Comment: check this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787291/use-jquery-to-get-a-list-of-classes

Comment: this may also help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651834/listing-known-css-classes-using-javascript

Comment: @Lukas - thank you but my question was heading more to how to crawl through all elements actually I know how to get all classes from one element - anyway great tip for others! :)

Comment: @C-Link - interesting link - it has nothing to do with this issue, but I may use it later :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery has an **attribute selector** - choose only elements which have class atribute :) 
Then split class attribute string (for cases like *class="one two"*) and add them to array (*dont forget to check if class is not empty or isnt already in the array*. Use **this.valueOf()** for checking and saving the string :)

```
var classes = [];
$('[class]').each(function(){
    $($(this).attr('class').split(' ')).each(function() { 
        if (this.length>0 && $.inArray(this.valueOf(), classes) === -1) {
            classes.push(this.valueOf());
        }    
    });
});
console.log("LIST START\n\n"+classes.join('\n')+"\n\nLIST END");
```

JSFiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/MWJKL/

Comment: getAttribute('class') works better than attr('class'), when svg elements comes into play

Answer (score 4):

Check only elements with the class attribute and split the value so you don't get duplicates

```
var classes = [];
$('[class]').each(function(){
    $.each($(this).attr('class').split(' '),function(i,className) { 
        if (className.length && $.inArray(className, classes) === -1) {
            classes.push(className);
        }    
    });
});
console.log(classes.join(','));
```

**EDIT** 
Fixed to iterate over an array instead of a jQuery object

Comment: Finally someone who really understood what output do I want :)

Comment: @jave.web There is no difference between this snippet and mine.

Comment: @Johan true. but this one has less white space ( more readable for me )  sorry :/ I gave you vote up anyway ;)

Comment: Found the bug ! :) inArray cant check for the objects, you just need to add JS's native method .valueOf() , because **this** in final scope is a string :)

Comment: @jave.web you're right I updated to iterate over the array instead of a jQuery object

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function(){

    var result = [];    

    $('*').each(function(k, v){

        var classNames = $(v).prop('class');

        if(classNames){

            var classes = classNames.split(' ');

            $.each(classes, function(k2, v2){

                if($.inArray(v2, result) === -1)
                    result.push(v2);
            });
        }

    });

    console.log(result);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZQZ8j/1/

Comment: This one is really good too (vote up), but there is no need to go through the whole javascript scoping if we have JS native valueOf() :)

Comment: @jave.web I'm aware that this can be written in a shorter and more optimized way. I wrote it like this because my intention was to make it readable for someone who's not very familiar with jQuery

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery("*").each(function () {
    var thisEl = jQuery(this);
    var thisClass = thisEl.attr("class");
    if (thisClass != undefined) { console.log(thisClass); }
});
```

Comment: I give you vote up, because its actually working, BUT not correctly it considers more classes in class attribute as one class :)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$(function(){
    var temp = {};    

    $('*').each(function(idx, el){
        var classNames = el.className;
        if(classNames){
            var classes = classNames.split(' ');
            $.each(classes, function(idx, clazz){
                temp[clazz] = true;
            });
        }
    });

    var result = $.map(temp, function(value, key){
        return key;
    })
    console.log(result);

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/48GFu/)

Comment: This one really is good one I just like koala's solution more :) , sad you cant chose second best answer :(

Answer (score 2):

ES6 solution using classList and without jQuery

```
var classes = []
document.querySelectorAll('[class]').forEach((node) => {
  node.classList.forEach((className) => {
    classes.push(className)
  })
})
console.log(classes)
```

Comment: Gave upvote for future, but although not explicitly, the question implies unique list (as in accepted answer) - I have a suggestion - what about using even more ES6 - `Set`s ? Super fast, **auto**unique :-) - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set , basically using `new Set()` instead of `[]` and `.add(...)` instead of `.push(...)` should be enough (note that with Sets  you DON'T need any uniqueness checking before adding item it does it natively :-) ) Tested, works super fast - https://jsfiddle.net/w1u8kq4g/

Answer (score 1):

You can jQuery [**has attribute selector**](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)

```
$("*[class]").each(function () {
    var classNames = this.attr("class");
    // Split classNames as shown in other answers
});
```

It will select elements which have the `class` attribute so no need to add check for undefined.

Comment: You seem to be messed up from other languages - this cant even work because you breaking two things: class is a reserved JavaScript word (cant name variable "classs") and you are calling jquery attr() method on non-jquery object ... you ment this: http://jsfiddle.net/eUH7N/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Firefox extension [Dust-Me](http://www.sitepoint.com/dustmeselectors/) that finds unused CSS selectors.

Comment: Jave.web wants to use jquery for this.

Comment: Sorry but @firian is right, I want to avoid third-party in this case.